How to create custom timeline widget in flutter
How to create Custom Timelime in flutter like bellow:

This is the code i have tried so far:
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 8.w,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
            gradient: const LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Color(0XFF402883),
                Color(0XFF6A55EA),
                Color(0XFF8F84D2),
                Color(0XFFADA6D5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.w),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Sign Up",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Create an account to invest & Trade",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                "Investment Order Submitted",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "You will be charged when the company's Escrow account opens(if it hasn't already)",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                "Funds In Transit",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Your Payment method has been charged,funds should arrive in escrow in 3-5 business days.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                "Funds Received",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Your investment finalization occurs at campaign close, potentially earlier with disbursement.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                "Funds Invested",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Your investment is complete and can find the details and ownership docs in your portfolio.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )

I have acheived this UI with above code:

Now to add these dots on the vertical line which is perfectly aligned with the title in front of it.
Thanks.

Just curious does the color matters or only bullet matters. If the color actually does not matter then. Use a stack and create this line with container and linear gradient. After that put your listview over it using Positioned widget. Use list view Or row and add bullet. After that position it such that the bullet is always over the container. This way you can align the title with bullet.

And if color really matters then use listTile for each item. Set the leading widget as the container with gradient. Use items length in listview and break your color into various color values using the index. For each listtile use the calculated start and end color value to design it.

can you give example with the code to make it more clear?

IntrinsicHeight class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible, like in this case for example. See Flutter's own documentation on this.
You can achieve the same result without sacrificing performance using other native Flutter components. Here is a complete example:
Code:
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
              bodyColor: Colors.white,
              displayColor: Colors.white,
            ),
      ),
      home: const TimelinePage(),
    );
  }
}

class TimelinePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TimelinePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: Timeline(
              timelineTiles: [
                TimelineTile(
                  title: "Sign Up",
                  description: "Create an account to invest & Trade",
                ),
                TimelineTile(
                  title: "Investment Order Submitted",
                  description:
                      "You will be charged when the company's Escrow account opens(if it hasn't already)",
                ),
                TimelineTile(
                  title: "Funds In Transit",
                  description:
                      "Your Payment method has been charged,funds should arrive in escrow in 3-5 business days.",
                ),
                TimelineTile(
                  title: "Funds Received",
                  description:
                      "Your investment finalization occurs at campaign close, potentially earlier with disbursement.",
                ),
                TimelineTile(
                  title: "Funds Invested",
                  description:
                      "Your investment is complete and can find the details and ownership docs in your portfolio.",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  const Timeline({
    super.key,
    required this.timelineTiles,
    this.sliderWidth = 12,
    this.circleSize = 8,
    this.gapBetweenSliderAndText = 6,
    this.gapTimelineTile = 12,
    this.sliderDecoration,
    this.hasAnimation = true,
  });

  final List<TimelineTile> timelineTiles;
  final double sliderWidth;
  final double circleSize;
  final double gapBetweenSliderAndText;
  final double gapTimelineTile;
  final BoxDecoration? sliderDecoration;
  final bool hasAnimation;

  @override
  State<Timeline> createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  double? widgetHeight;
  GlobalKey textColumnKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) calculateHeight();
    });
  }

  void calculateHeight() {
    if (textColumnKey.currentContext != null) {
      RenderBox renderBox =
          textColumnKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      setState(() => widgetHeight = renderBox.size.height);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant Timeline oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) calculateHeight();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: widget.hasAnimation
              ? const Duration(milliseconds: 300)
              : Duration.zero,
          curve: Curves.decelerate,
          width: widget.sliderWidth,
          height: widgetHeight ?? 0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: widget.sliderWidth < widget.circleSize
                ? (widget.circleSize - widget.sliderWidth) / 2
                : 0,
          ),
          decoration: widget.sliderDecoration ??
              BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0XFF402883),
                    Color(0XFF6A55EA),
                    Color(0XFF8F84D2),
                    Color(0XFFADA6D5),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
        ),
        Column(
          key: textColumnKey,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: List.generate(
            widget.timelineTiles.length,
            (index) => Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width:
                          max((widget.sliderWidth - widget.circleSize) / 2, 0),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: widget.circleSize,
                      height: widget.circleSize,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width:
                          max((widget.sliderWidth - widget.circleSize) / 2, 0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: widget.gapBetweenSliderAndText),
                    Text(
                      widget.timelineTiles[index].title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: max(widget.sliderWidth, widget.circleSize) +
                        widget.gapBetweenSliderAndText,
                    bottom: widget.timelineTiles.length - 1 == index
                        ? 0
                        : widget.gapTimelineTile,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    widget.timelineTiles[index].description,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TimelineTile {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  TimelineTile({
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
  });
}

Note that in this example you can change the spacing and even the layout of the elements as you prefer.
You just change the timelineTiles list inside Timeline using your state controller and generate as the data is provided by the API. I took the liberty of adding a slight animation to ensure a better visual experience.
Outputs:
Same example as the question

or
Alternative layout


Thank you so much. highly appreciate your efforts. It perfectly worked.

(Keep in mind that I removed 10.sp 12.w 8.w and other things like this, so don't forget to add them in your code)
Because the first item description is only 1. line it is hard to set foxed height
Use this code:
 IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 8,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    gradient: const LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Color(0XFF402883),
                        Color(0XFF6A55EA),
                        Color(0XFF8F84D2),
                        Color(0XFFADA6D5),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: index == 0
                                ? 2
                                : index == 1
                                    ? 51
                                    : index + 6 + 52,
                            right: 2,
                            left: 2),
                        height: 4,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                const Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Sign Up",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Create an account to invest & Trade",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 14),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 55,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Investment Order Submitted",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "You will be charged when the company's Escrow account opens(if it hasn't already)",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 55,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Funds In Transit",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Your Payment method has been charged,funds should arrive in escrow in 3-5 business days.",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 55,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Funds Received",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Your investment finalization occurs at campaign close, potentially earlier with disbursement.",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 55,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Funds Invested",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Your investment is complete and can find the details and ownership docs in your portfolio.",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

Here is the result:


the dots are not aligned with the titles.

Wait a sec I will fix it

that would be great! Thanks in advance. But make sure that it is dynamically aligned as the title and description are coming from backend.

so the item length can be changed?

yes i am getting this data from backend.

Wait. I will handle it

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Done Check it out.

And a user might change the text font size.
When you hardcode values like height: 55 it's not a good idea

Since there is no API, It is what to comes to my mind, if there ware APIs available, itemcount would be length of that received list length

Use CustomScrollView together with SliverStack from this package called sliver_tools. Stack the container to cover vertical space and align it accordingly such that the ListTile leading widget always at top of the container. Below is an example code:
class DotListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DotListWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<DotListWidget> createState() => _DotListWidgetState();
}

class _DotListWidgetState extends State<DotListWidget> {
  List<String> titles = [
    "The Art of War",
    "To Kill a Mockingbird",
    "1984",
    "Pride and Prejudice",
    "The Great Gatsby",
    "Moby-Dick",
    "The Catcher in the Rye",
    "Brave New World",
    "One Hundred Years of Solitude",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
    "The Hobbit",
    "The Alchemist",
    "The Da Vinci Code",
    "The Hunger Games",
    "The Shining",
    "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
    "The Catcher in the Rye",
    "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer",
    "Crime and Punishment",
    "War and Peace: A Novel by Leo Tolstoy",
    "The Brothers Karamazov: A Novel by Fyodor Dostoevsky",
    "The Count of Monte Cristo: A Novel by Alexandre Dumas",
    "Anna Karenina: A Novel by Leo Tolstoy",
    "Gone with the Wind: A Novel by Margaret Mitchell",
    "Atlas Shrugged: A Novel by Ayn Rand",
    "In Search of Lost Time: A Novel by Marcel Proust",
    "The Stand: A Novel by Stephen King",
    "The Grapes of Wrath: A Novel by John Steinbeck",
    "Les Misérables: A Novel by Victor Hugo"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverStack(
          insetOnOverlap: false, // defaults to false
          children: <Widget>[
            SliverPositioned(
              left: 16,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 10,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0XFF402883),
                      Color(0XFF6A55EA),
                      Color(0XFF8F84D2),
                      Color(0XFFADA6D5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    radius: 5,
                  ),
                  title: Text(titles[index]),
                );
              },
              itemCount: titles.length,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

This way the title will be always aligned with bullet and the item in list can be dynamic.


